# usage of 'neither.. nor', 'not...or' and 'not.... nor'

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, negation

Are these sentences grammatical?

> 1. I neither usually wake up at 6 am, nor do I like to wake up at 5 am.
> 2. We neither wear the same clothes, nor do we eat the same food.
> 3. We don't wear the same clothes or eat the same food.
> 4. We don't wear the same clothes nor do we eat the same food.

Comment: hehe I asked before the same thing. link[https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126696/do-native-speakers-use-double-negatives-in-order-to-mean-positive-situations-rea] FYI please.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answers for each sentence:

> Number 1
>
> > Original: I neither usually wake up at 6 am, nor do I like to wake up at 5 am.
> >
> > Proper: I don't usually wake up at 6 A.M., nor do I wake up at 5 A.M.
>
> Number 2
>
> > Original: We neither wear the same clothes, nor do we eat the same food.
> >
> > Proper: We don't wear the same clothes, nor do we eat the same food.
>
> Number 3
>
> > Original: We don't wear the same clothes or eat the same food.
> >
> > Proper: We don't wear the same clothes or eat the same food.
>
> Number 4
>
> > Original: We don't wear the same clothes nor do we eat the same food.
> >
> > Proper: We don't wear the same clothes, nor eat the same food.

Comment: I would suggest you replace "Proper" with "Typical", as all the sentences are grammatical and understandable. It is merely that "neither/nor" is not typical usage, and would sound stilted to most listeners for the examples given.